# WSO2 Analytics: Error while connecting to Table 'ApiUserPerAppAgg_MONTHS'

Tags: mysql, wso2, wso2-api-manager

Facing the following error when running WSO2 Analytics 3.1.0

The database connection is fine: Able to connect to the MYSQL DB
The Table is also present

Mysql version: 5.7
and sql connector: 5.1.42

deployment.yaml

```
  #Data source for APIM Analytics
  - name: APIM_ANALYTICS_DB
    description: Datasource used for APIM Analytics
    jndiConfig:
      name: jdbc/APIM_ANALYTICS_DB
    definition:
      type: RDBMS
      configuration:
        jdbcUrl: 'jdbc:mysql://wso2db:3306/analytics3db?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false'
        username: 'xxxxxxx'
        password: 'xxxxxxxxx'
        driverClassName: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
        maxPoolSize: 50
        idleTimeout: 60000
        connectionTestQuery: SELECT 1
        validationTimeout: 30000
        isAutoCommit: false
```

tried different SQL connector, from .47, but still facing this issue

[2020-10-16 13:21:02,257] ERROR {io.siddhi.core.table.Table} - Error on 'APIMApiVersionUsageSummarySiddhi'. Failed to initialize store for table name 'ApiUserPerAppAgg_MONTHS' Error while connecting to Table 'ApiUserPerAppAgg_MONTHS', will retry in '10 sec'. io.siddhi.core.exception.ConnectionUnavailableException: Failed to initialize store for table name 'ApiUserPerAppAgg_MONTHS'
at io.siddhi.extension.store.rdbms.RDBMSEventTable.connect(RDBMSEventTable.java:1237)
at io.siddhi.core.table.record.AbstractQueryableRecordTable.connectAndLoadCache(AbstractQueryableRecordTable.java:206)
at io.siddhi.core.table.Table.connectWithRetry(Table.java:406)
at io.siddhi.core.table.Table$1.run(Table.java:422)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: io.siddhi.extension.store.rdbms.exception.RDBMSTableException: Error in looking up database type: HikariPool-5 - Connection is not available, request timed out after 30028ms.
at io.siddhi.extension.store.rdbms.util.RDBMSTableUtils.lookupDatabaseInfo(RDBMSTableUtils.java:422)
at io.siddhi.extension.store.rdbms.util.RDBMSTableUtils.lookupCurrentQueryConfigurationEntry(RDBMSTableUtils.java:453)
at io.siddhi.extension.store.rdbms.RDBMSEventTable.connect(RDBMSEventTable.java:1093)
... 10 more

Comment: few things to verify? Does wso2db:3306 is accessible from the analytics node? Does analytics3db DB is already created?

Comment: yes, it is accessible, DB also created already...

Answer (score 0):

Based on the logs, seems like there are no available connections. So as a solution you can increase the data source connection pool size and check.
ex:

```
    maxPoolSize: 100
```

Also, make sure DB is supported max connection defined in the `maxPoolSize`. If not increase it in the DB too.

Answer (score 0):

In here change the name section under jndiConfig into as following

name: jdbc/analytics3db

By changing this my connection is established with database.

```
- name: APIM_ANALYTICS_DB
description: Datasource used for APIM Analytics
jndiConfig:
  name: jdbc/analytics3db
definition:
  type: RDBMS
  configuration:
    jdbcUrl: 'jdbc:mysql://wso2db:3306/analytics3db?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false'
    username: 'xxxxxxx'
    password: 'xxxxxxxxx'
    driverClassName: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    maxPoolSize: 50
    idleTimeout: 60000
    connectionTestQuery: SELECT 1
    validationTimeout: 30000
    isAutoCommit: false
```

Even check whether in .siddhi file in @store you have datasource as following
@store(type='rdbms',datasource="APIM_ANALYTICS_DB")